# Mostrar option bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, angular, angular5

Con este codigo me sale la primera options del ngfor y no se como mostrar primero el primer options que es por defecto. Como lo podria hacer?
Por defecto me sale el options del ngFor y yo quiero el primer option.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Grup</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="operato" formControlName="company">
           <option disabled selected value>Escoja</option>
           <option *ngFor="let operat of operato;">{{operato.companyName}}</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Es parecida pero ahora no me sale el primer options por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo tienes me funciona... O puedes intentar remplazando el `disabled` por `hidden`. Te dejo las dos opciones funcionales.

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Grup</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="operato" formControlName="company">
           <option value="" disabled selected>Escoja</option>
           <option *ngFor="let operat of operato;">{{operato.companyName}}</option>
       </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Grup</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="operato" formControlName="company">
           <option value="" hidden selected>Escoja</option>
           <option *ngFor="let operat of operato;">{{operato.companyName}}</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Ahora, al seleccionar una opción diferente a `Escoja`, debes recargar la pagina para que te muestre nuevamente esa opción.